# Placement of a temperature sensor for accurate readings

Tags: temperature

I have the remote temperature sensor for my Garmin fitness tracker.  The data it records is nowhere near as insane as what the watch itself gets (who figured it was a good idea to put a thermometer in a black case likely exposed to the sun??) I still find that the placement on a strap on the bottom of my pack still is being substantially contaminated by the sun--no, it wasn't 20 degrees warmer in the morning (with the sun at my back) than the afternoon (returning--and even there I think the numbers are a bit high.)

Where should I place it to get as realistic a picture as possible?  I am typically in full sun.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have an vented white container, similar to those on weather stations you won't get an accurate reading. Your best bet might be to have it in a white vented container in an open/mesh side pocket of your pack (possibly under a strap might work - though risk of slipping out), but even this will get some residual heat from the pack and make the readings out by a bit. How much readings might be out is difficult to say, but I would guess 1-2 degrees C maximum.

A weather station one looks like this image from Wikipedia, the temperature probe is inside the white ribbed container on the right-hand side of the image:

[image: weather station]

Attribution: Garytx at English Wikipedia, CC BY-SA 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, via Wikimedia Commons

Any suitable container would need to be similarly vented and not insulated (i.e. not inside a pack) so as to accurately reflect the shade air temperature.

Comment: Within a couple of C would be fine, I just want a reasonable approximation of the actual weather I encountered.